# I'm trying to create a maze but my cpu usage or memory usage get overload when running the game how can i fix it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I added to the Hierarch two cubes.
The first one i attached the script.
The second cube i dragged to the Inspector to the Wall Holder.

When running the game my whole pc stuck i had to shutdown the pc and restart over.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MazeGenerator : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject wallHolder;
    public float wallLength = 1.0f;
    public int xSize = 5;
    public int ySize = 5;

    private Vector3 initialPos;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        CreateWalls();  
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void CreateWalls()
    {
        wallHolder = new GameObject();
        wallHolder.name = "Maze";

        initialPos = new Vector3((-xSize / 2) + wallLength / 2, (-ySize / 2) + wallLength / 2);
        Vector3 myPos = initialPos;
        GameObject tempWall;

        //For x axis
        for (int i = 0; i < ySize; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= xSize; j++)
            {
                myPos = new Vector3(initialPos.x + (j * wallLength) - wallLength / 2, 0.0f, initialPos.z + (i * wallLength) - wallLength / 2);
                tempWall = Instantiate(wallHolder, myPos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                tempWall.transform.parent = wallHolder.transform;
            }
        }

        //for y axis
        for (int i = 0; i <= ySize; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < xSize; j++)
            {
                myPos = new Vector3(initialPos.x + (j * wallLength), 0.0f, initialPos.z + (i * wallLength) - wallLength);
                tempWall = Instantiate(wallHolder, myPos, Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 90.0f, 0.0f)) as GameObject;
                tempWall.transform.parent = wallHolder.transform;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't looked through the actual code yet but at first glance 2x nested loops looks weird for a 2d maze.. Shouldn't it be one loop that "moves" in the Y-axis and inside it one loop that moves in the X-axis?

Comment: You haven't provided enough code for us to see what's going on. You need to give us a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some weirdness going on in how you are assigning and referencing your wallHolder property. Pay close attention to how you are handling it. It would be a good idea to break it down like so :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MazeGenerator: MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject wallObjectRoot;
    public GameObject wallObjectReference;
    public float wallLength = 1.0f;
    public int xSize = 5;
    public int ySize = 5;

    private Vector3 initialPos;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        if (wallObjectReference == null || wallObjectRoot == null){
            Debug.LogError("WallHolder properties need to be assigned to MazeGenerator");
        }

        CreateWalls();  
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void CreateWalls()
    {


        initialPos = new Vector3((-xSize / 2) + wallLength / 2, (-ySize / 2) + wallLength / 2);

        //For x axis
        for (int i = 0; i < ySize; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= xSize; j++)
            {
                Vector3 spawnPos = new Vector3(initialPos.x + (j * wallLength) - wallLength / 2, 0.0f, initialPos.z + (i * wallLength) - wallLength / 2);
                GameObject wallObject = Instantiate(wallObjectReference, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
                wallObject.transform.parent = wallObjectRoot.transform;
            }
        }

        //for y axis
        for (int i = 0; i <= ySize; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < xSize; j++)
            {
                Vector3 spawnPos = new Vector3(initialPos.x + (j * wallLength), 0.0f, initialPos.z + (i * wallLength) - wallLength);
                GameObject wallObject = Instantiate(wallObjectReference, spawnPos, Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 90.0f, 0.0f));
                wallObject.transform.parent = wallObjectRoot.transform;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Put the MazeGenerator script on an object titled MazeGenerator. Using the Inspector, assign a GameObject in the scene to be the wallObjectRoot, and assign a Prefab from your project to be the wallObjectReference. You could also use a gameObject from your scene to be the wallObjectReference, but that's a little wonky.

Also, you should be able to exit out of the unity process if it freezes up by cancelling it from windows Task Manager (Ctrl+Shift+Esc).